# home button pressed

Tags: android

What exactly happens when I press home button in Android? 
Because when I open it again after home button pressed, it has series of bugs. 
I need to know it to track down the point that causes that bugs.

UPDATE:
when pressing home button, application goes to background and `onPause()` is called and saves the state of UI, however it does not save state of application, like variables, custom views. And you have to save them manually, as Oren explained.

Comment: onPause() get called, and the app goes in background. What do you mean with series of bugs?

Comment: Do you refer to hardware home button, or home button in Action Bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technichally? Anything can happen, from just `onPause` being called, to the device killing the app to free up memory, to the user shutting down and restarting the device. Your app should handle all of these possibilities.

Further reading : [android activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)

Comment: it just calls super constructor. I thought it holds the state of application.

Comment: well. if you call through to `super.onPause()` it will save the state of all you views, maintaining the UI. however that is not the same as the application state. any internal variables, costum views etc need to be saved manually. look at examples online of `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onCreate()` to see how its done.

Answer (score 2):

When you press Home Button your Application/Activity goes in background and when you open it again it resume from the same position as it was until it was being killed/closed by the OS.

[Activity Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) will give you a clear idea about it.

Comment: I thought, it would just call onPause() and onResume() it would resume from previous position. But I cannot swipe fragments anymore. Do I have to save my applications state when onPause() is called?

Comment: You are right, Activities `onPause()` is called when you press Home Button and `onResume()` is called when you resume the Application.